# Move WooCommerce Subscription below orders

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a Wordpress website on which I'm using WooCommerce & WooCommerce Subscriptions Add-on.
The problem is that under My Account page, the "My Subscriptions" field appears above the Welcome message. Please check this screenshot: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/48854464/Screen%20Shot%202014-10-18%20at%202.11.59%20AM.png

I would like the My Subscriptions field to appear below the welcome message.

I have no clue what to modify.. :(

PS: Using Avada Theme.

Could someone please help me? This is the website in question:

http://www.twistedperfectionism.com/my-account/

Answer (score 0):

Open file `/wp-content/themes/avada/woocommerce/myaccount/my-account.php`, find these 2 lines in this file:

```
<?php woocommerce_get_template('user-welcome.php'); ?>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_my_account' ); ?>
```

Please check whether they are in same sequence. If not, keep it same as above. `do_action( 'woocommerce_before_my_account' );` should be below `woocommerce_get_template('user-welcome.php');`